# Are there any good memory profiling tools for windows mobile 6.0?

Tags: windows-mobile, memory-profiling

I googled it a bit around but couldn't find any up to the mark solution. Then thought of having a dedicated question on StackOverflow. Anybody has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you are exactly looking for.

If a dotnet app has to been profiled, you can use the Compact Framework Perfmon.

If a c/c++ app has to been profiled, you may look at Entrek solutions.

If you just need an overview of memory use, see, for example, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32297/Visualizing-the-Windows-Mobile-Virtual-Memory-Mons

See also http://community.intermec.com/t5/General-Development-Developer/Slaying-the-virtual-memory-monster/td-p/16764

If you have access to DevHealth (a windows mobile OEM tool) you may use that as a very detailed memory analysis tool.